# How do you relocate the Zero Page on a 65816

Tags: commodore, 65816

**Background information**

As a modern days PHP developer with a passing interest in 8-bit technologies, I'm a little sketchy on real low level stuff. Although I've worked with the Z80 processor, and done some MIPs assembly at University, I'm least well versed in the 65x processor family.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

What I want to do is to relocate the zero page to 0xd300 for my application - I've had a obligatory Internet search but am not able to find a good example that I am able to understand. I'm working in 65c02 but on a 65816 processor; I have found out, thanks to a friend, that you can only relocate the zero page in native mode, not emulation mode as it's not supported by the 65c02. This isn't an issue as I can switch to native mode for what I'm doing and revert to emulation mode should I want to return gracefully to BASIC (well, not only that I know).

If someone could also provide an example for the 8502 (Commodore C128) as well please as I know that has a relocatable zero page. I know that's two questions in one, but it's related to what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct Page register `D` is a 16-bit register specifying which 256-byte page within bank 0 that should be the current Direct Page (what you call Zero Page).

There are a couple of different instructions you can use to write to `D`. So e.g. something like this should work:

```
rep #$20  ; 16-bit accumulator
lda #$100
tcd       ; transfer 16-bit accumulator to D
```

Note that the page is allowed to start on any byte boundary. So you could e.g. set `D=2` and have a direct page at `[0002, 0101]`.

Comment: Excellent. This is very useful to know as the first 16-bits of the zero page on the Commodore C64 and C128 are taken by the processor ports and data direction registers. It might therefore be useful to set the D register to `0x0002` as you've suggested.

Comment: One caveat: if the Direct Page doesn't start on a page boundary (i.e., the the Direct Page Register isn't a multiple of 256) then all instructions using Direct Page addressing modes take an extra cycle to execute. (The CPU has special logic to detect when the low-order byte of the DPR is zero, in which case it simply ORs the direct page offset with the DPR, but if the low-order byte of DPR is non-zero it must do an add with carry, which takes an extra cycle.)